# Maven OpenAM - not finding dependency in the repository

Tags: java, maven, openam

We are trying to use OpenAM in our project, we use maven. I have added below things in my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>forgerock</id>
        <url>http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
        <artifactId>amserver</artifactId>
        <version>${openam.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But whenever I run `mvn clean install` I get below error:

> Could not find artifact org.forgerock
>   nam:amserver:jar:10.0.0 in forgerock (http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases) -> [Help 1]

I tried deleting folder from .m2 folder, did `mvn clean install -U` but still no luck. I got the maven syntax from official url: https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Using+Maven+and+OpenAM.

Can anyone please guide me in this?

Comment: Did you try to put the version manually? Their repository seems to be well configured : http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases/org/forgerock/openam/openam/

Comment: Yes I gave version manually.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you shared they noted that artifact IDs may differ in latest versions. Try `openam-core` instead of `amserver`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no 10.0.0 version in the repository, only 10.0.1. I filed https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/COMMWEB-117 for this.

However why would you use such an old/outdated version?

You should go for 11.0.0. If you do note that the artifacts have changed due to mavenizing.

Answer (score 0):

As Bernhard said: the artifacts were unfortunately missing from the Maven repository. It has been added now, so your Maven project should compile now just fine.